# Simple math library for the web

Tags: math, javascript

I'm looking for a math JavaScript API to show formulas on a web site and allow users to input formulas too (for instance, using a `<textarea/>`).

The API should be able to parse text strings, such as 3x^2+2 or sqrt(x/(x+5)) building "automagically" fractional layouts, integral symbols and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org). It's used at various sites, such as [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) and [www.mathoverflow.org](http://www.mathoverflow.org).